# enabling UPS Shipping module for Drupal Commerce Kickstart

Tags: drupal-7, e-commerce, ups, drupal-commerce

I enabled the UPS shipping module for the latest version of drupal commerce kickstart: https://drupal.org/project/commerce_ups

I added the product weight and dimension fields to the products. Also configured my UPS API Credentials.

When I checkout with the product with these fields, I get no option for shipping with UPS. I followed the instructions in the modules README.txt

How do I get the UPS shipping option to come up for the customers?

Comment: did you find an answer to this? We've been having the same issue.

Comment: Did you configure the UPS shipping method (rule): /admin/commerce/config/shipping/methods/ups